# Python - Why is the created array empty?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

Here is a MWE (minimal-working example) that I have:

```
import numpy as np

errors = np.array([])
for i in range(7):
    np.append(errors, i)
print(errors)
```

Unfortunately, the output from Jupyter Notebook is only an empty array, but why?

Comment: Don't use `numpy.append` in a loop - even if you fix your bug, using `numpy.append` in a loop is severely inefficient due to quadratic amounts of unnecessary copying.

Comment: `NameError: name 'np' is not defined`. This is not a MWE. What is np ? numpy ?

Comment: ditto with the "what is np ?" - does this example run? is an include missing?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly, "why is the created array empty", it's pretty simple: you created an empty array.

```py
errors = np.array([]) # this array is empty!
```

From the documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html

> `numpy.append(arr, values, axis=None)`
>
> Returns:   append : ndarray A copy of arr with values appended to axis.
>   Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and
>   filled.

Your array `errors` is only assigned once, you'll need to re-assign the appended array to `errors` to get the result you are expecting, else it will stay empty.

```py
errors = np.append(errors, i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because numpy.append() does not work in-place, i.e. the old object is not overwritten. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

errors = np.array([])
for i in range(7):
    errors = np.append(errors, i)
print(errors)
```

I would recommend going with a simple list in your case:

```
errors = []
for i in range(7):
    errors +=[i]
print(errors)
```